# How can I fix the "Error: 'default' is not exported by..." when using formdata-node default import?

Tags: node.js, typescript, export, rollup, umd

### Summary

I feel like I've hit my head against a wall too many times trying to figure out where I may be going wrong. I have a simple piece of typescript code:

```js
import FormDataI from 'formdata-node'

const c = new FormDataI()

export { c }
```

That im trying to compile down to umd using rollup and typescript. For some reason, I cant seem to get it to compile correctly and instead receive an error message:

```
[!] Error: 'default' is not exported by node_modules/formdata-node/lib/FormData.js, imported by index.ts
https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#error-name-is-not-exported-by-module
index.ts (1:7)
```

Any suggestions as to where I may be going wrong? Here is a [sample project](https://gitlab.com/jdalrymple/sample2) that throws the error.

### Things I've tried

1. Playing with various typescript settings such as esModuleInterlop
2. Playing with the commonjs properties such as [requireReturnsDefault](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/commonjs#requirereturnsdefault)
3. Stepping through the rollup code hoping to find the import error. It appears to not notice the export from formdata-node which is [exported](https://github.com/octet-stream/form-data/blob/master/lib/FormData.js#L592) using `module.exports.default` and `module.exports`

**UPDATE**
In the case of the above situation, I could simply set it as a global/external since FormData is supported in the browser natively. The question is, why does this error appear at all though?